# Passing data between View Controllers using segues. Not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I have attempted to pass an Integer value using a Segue from one view controller to another. I used this thread to help me:
[Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers).

So I followed the steps from the top question, declared my integer in the view controller that is receiving the info's header, and likewise imported that header into the view controller that is sending the info's header.
I created a modal segue that I though would both create the integer's value and present the second view controller. It only presents the second view controller. In addition when I close my app it freezes my whole phone!

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"useCheat"]){
        begin *controller = (begin *)segue.destinationViewController;
// I get a warning report here that says, "unused variable 'controller'". I could not figure out a fix.
        if (codeForAllActive == YES) {
            score = 10;
        }
        else if (codeForOneActive == YES) {
            score = 9999975;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, useCheat is the segue identifier. begin is the view controller receiving the info. (the info is the value of score).
The value of score does not change in begin.

If I do this instead:

```
  -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
            if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"useCheat"]){
                begin *controller = (begin *)segue.destinationViewController;
                if (codeForAllActive == YES) {
                    controller.score = 10;
                }
                else if (codeForOneActive == YES) {
                    controller.score = 9999975;
                }
            }
        }
```

I get an error at `controller.score`  that reads: property score not found on object type begin. 
So in begin.h (begin is the destination VC) I create a property for score:

```
  @property(strong,nonatomic) NSInteger score;
```

Once I do that, I get this error: unexpected '@' in program.
I took out the '@' and I get another error: missing parameter score.

Comment: Try `controller.score` , you are not using `controller` object. It is the bridge to pass data from current view to destination view.

Comment: does not work comes up with error: expected a ';'

Comment: begin is the view controller i would like to send the value to

Answer (score 0):

Try like following `code`

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    SecondViewController * secondVC = (SecondViewController *) segue.destinationViewController;
    secondVC.intVariable = 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"useCheat"]){
        begin *controller = (begin *)segue.destinationViewController;
// I get a warning report here that says, "unused variable 'controller'". I could not figure out a fix.
        if (codeForAllActive) {
           controller.score = 10;
       } else if (codeForOneActive) {
           controller.score = 9999975;
       }
   }
}
```

@rdelmar Pointed it out, declare score as NSInteger property in *destinationViewController*

```
@property(strong,nonatomic)NSInteger score;
```

Comment: brings up error: "property 'score' not found on object type of 'begin *'

Comment: @jose, you need to create a property called score in controller to receive the information.

Comment: i have another error now: unexpected '@' in program and also the problem still remains

Comment: Where did the problem occurred?show that block of code. And on which view this is occurring? Use Breakpoints.

Comment: I edited the question to take you through everything

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"useCheat"]){
    begin *controller = (begin *)segue.destinationViewController;

        if (codeForAllActive == YES) {
        controller.score = 10;
        } 
       else if (codeForOneActive == YES) {
       controller.score = 9999975;
       }
    }
}
```